# Connect to Docker SQL Server 2017 Container on MAC OSX via SQL Operations Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, azure-data-studio

I have the following SQL Server 2017 container up and running as per -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                    CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
910d34ad3c3e        microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest   "/bin/sh -c /opt/m..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:1401->1433/tcp   sql1
```

I can connect inside docker container with SQLCMD.

But I am not sure what to enter in SQL Operations Studio to get it to connect -

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Soon as posted this, realised the port on the MAC side was on 1401 and not 1433 like in a lot of other examples I was reading.

Server Name should have been : 192.168.2.28,1401

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: In windows i have the same problem, you know the port for windows, the default 1433 not work.

Comment: Sorry @chalo I do not, but please add it to your comment if you do find out.